# Create User From External Provider With + In name

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Question: Is there a way to escape special characters in Azure SQL User Create Statement?

Context:
When trying to create a database user from ADD in an Azure SQL database I receive an error that the principal cannot be found. This only happens when creating the user for a Principal with a + in the name.

This is the statement that I use to create database users. Usually this works.

```
CREATE USER [Most Application Names] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

However when the Application Name has a + in it I receive an error.

```
CREATE USER [Application Name With + Sign] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

> Principal 'Application Name With + Sign' could not be found or this principal type is not supported.

I have confirmed the name in AAD for the tenant that the database authenticates against.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replace the + with a %2B in the SQL command and it worked.